# Redirect url and rewrite it

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I'm currently struggling with url redirect with iis.

I need to accomplish the following:

- Redirect www.site.de to www.site.de/subdir
- show www.site.de in the browser (rewrite?)

I managed to do the first thing, but can't do the second.
I tried several ways but couldn't do it. :/

Code for first point:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="in a subfolder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.de/subdir" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

So is there anyway to get rid of the sub directory in the url?

Background is:
My site is in a subdir in wwwroot, but i don't want this information in the public url so i need to redirect it to the right sub directory, but outgoing urls must omit the sub directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<rule name="in a subfolder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/subdir/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I've changed the action to `Rewrite` and added a match token of `{R:0}` to the output to send them to the matching url within the regular expression within `subdir`.

---

E.g. given:

http://www.domain.de/default.htm

This will render:

http://www.domain.de/subdir/default.htm

But still show `http://www.domain.de/default.htm` in the browser.

Comment: I see, i thougt the wrong way. I just have to point those url requests to the right directory. Thanks!